# How to add a fixed AppBar over multiple scrollable PageViews in flutter

Tags: android, user-interface, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to add a transparent appBar over a PageView.

The Pageview is implemented using Stacks in Flutter, So that all the content is placed over an image. Since it is different than how Tabs work, I need to place an appBar such that even during Scrolling b/w multiple pageViews, the appBar remains Fixed at given position.

I am using following Code to achieve this, but it is showing various kind of errors.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:page_transformer/data.dart';
import 'package:page_transformer/intro_page_item.dart';
import 'package:page_transformer/page_transformer.dart';

class IntroPageView extends StatelessWidget{


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> children = new List();



    return
        Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          _buildBackground(),
          _buildforeground()

        ],
      );
  }



  Widget _buildforeground() => new AppBar(

  title: Text('Antara',
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,),


  );

  Widget _buildBackground() =>  PageTransformer(
    pageViewBuilder: (context, visibilityResolver) {
      return PageView.builder(
        controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 1.0),
        itemCount: sampleItems.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final item = sampleItems[index];
          final pageVisibility =
          visibilityResolver.resolvePageVisibility(index);

          return IntroPageItem(
            item: item,
            pageVisibility: pageVisibility,
          );
        },
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Please tell me where i am wrong, Also, i forgot to mention that the pageviews are stateful widgets, and the PageTransformer widget is used to give parallax effect while scrolling b/w pageviews.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply two changes to your code to force the height

- Remove the `StackFit.expand` because it makes the bar to occupy the whole screen
- Wrap the `AppBar` with a Container or SizedBox and provide a height to constrain it

And finally set the transparent color and elevation to 0.0

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> children = new List();

    return Stack(
      //fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: [
        _buildBackground(),
        _buildforeground(),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildforeground() => SizedBox(
        height: 80.0,
        child: new AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0.0,
          title: Text(
            'Antara',
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Comment: Thank You very much sir. It actually solved my problem, thank you once again.